# What is the meaning of ^ and $ in Apache HTTPD RewriteRule?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, httpd.conf

I have successfully added the following code to my Apache HTTPD configuration:

```
# Force www.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
# Force https (SSL)
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Although it works as expected, I have a theoretical question:

Why are there a `^` and `$` in 3rd line enforcing "www.", and not in the 6th line enforcing "https"?

Sincerely, Dovid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For both of your regex patterns `^(.*)$` and `(.*)` will behave same. However guess what, you don't need to use any of them. In fact it is far less error prone also to not to use `.*` and use `%{REQUEST_URI}` variable that matches full URI (not the relative one like `.*`). So I suggest change your rules to this:

```
# Force www.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]

# Force https (SSL)
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

- Flag `NE` is used for not escaping. It is useful to have this flag in case your original URI has some special characters like `#`  or `(,),[,]` etc.
- `^` in `RewriteRule` pattern above does nothing but returns true for every match since `^` means start position of a string and it will be always match.
- Both rules can be combined into a single rule but it will look a bit complicated.

Here it is:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

Here is the explanation of this rule:

- `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC,OR]`: if `HOST_NAME` doesn't start with `www.`
- `[NC,OR]`: Ignore case match and `OR`s next condition
- `RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on`: `HTTPS` is not turned on
- `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]`: This condition will always match since `www.` is an optional match here. It is used to capture substring of `HTTP_HOST` without starting `www.` by using `(.+)` pattern in capture group #1 (to be back-referenced as `%1` later). Note that `(?:..)` is a non-capturing group.
- `RewriteRule ^ https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]`: `^` will always match. This rule will redirect to `https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI}` with `R=301` code by adding `https://` and `www.` to `%1`. `%1` is back-reference of capture group #1 from `RewriteCond`, as mentioned above.

Answer (score 3):

If using Apache's module [mod_rewrite](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2t/mod/mod_rewrite.html) then you can define a [RewriteRule](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/HTTPD/RewriteRule).

#### RewriteRule uses a Regular Expression

The keyword or directive `RewriteRule` is followed by a **[Regular Expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression)** (also known as *RegEx* or *pattern*). This *RegEx* (e.g. `^(.*)$`) is used to match input URL's in order to rewrite them.

#### Regular Expressions are coded using special characters

Within a *RegEx* pattern `^` marks the start of the line to match, whereas the end is denoted by `$`.

Both are called **metacharacters** and have special meaning:

> **^**: Matches the starting position within the string. In line-based tools, it matches the starting position of any line.
>
> **$**: Matches the ending position of the string or the position just before a string-ending newline. In line-based tools, it matches the ending position of any line.

#### Why they often are obsolete?

Since URLs reaching the HTTP-server always are represented by one single line, these *line-delimiting* metacharacters can also be omitted without affecting the pattern/rewrite-rule.

Comment: B"H

Hello hc_dev

I understand now why in this case there is no difference, Thank you for that.

Sincerely, Dovid.

Answer (score 2):

They're the same. There's no difference between `^(.*)$` and `(.*)`.

`.*` matches any string. `^` and `$` don't change that since all strings have a start and end.

Comment: B"H

Thanks Anonymous for your reply.

Is that mentioned in any documentation?

Sincerely, Dovid.

Comment: @Dovid These are regular expression control characters. `^` means "start of string". `$` means "end of string". In this *particular* case, they have equivalent meanings. In other scenarios, they may be important.

Comment: @Dovid No, but there are some examples on https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html that show `.*` matching everything. `^` and `$` don't change that.

Comment: B"H

Thanks again, Anonymous, for this additional reply.

Sincerely, Dovid.

Comment: Don't be that person who ... answers concisely without explaining ;-)

Comment: @hc_dev True. Updated ;-)

Answer (score 1):

It depends if you made the certificate for the domain without www or with www.

In the provided example the redirection (6th line) is done to the domain **without** www. That guarantees that the correct certificate will be served and browser won't display an alert while visiting your site.

Comment: B"H

Thank you Skatox for your reply.

If "www." was absent, then the first half of the code (3rd line) adds both the "www." and the "https". If the "www." was already present, then isn't that part of "{HTTP_HOST} in the 6th line? Because if not, then the address would stay without "www.", while as a matter of fact "www." is always added.

I must admit, that I have no idea how I can check which of the two, www. or non-www., has the certificate issued to it by my Hostgator provider. Didn't even know that makes a difference.

Sincerely, Dovid.

Comment: HTTP_HOST is just the domain, nothing else. If my answer helped you remember to mark it as solved and vote for it :)