# RewriteRule not doing the job on blog subfolder

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, httpd.conf

The following code, which was discussed recently on [another post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59416797/what-is-the-meaning-of-and-in-apache-httpd-rewriterule), works as a charm on [my website](https://www.doviddebresser.info/) and [subdomain](https://www.debresser-translations.com/):

```
RewriteEngine On
# Force www.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
# Force https (SSL)
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

However, on the `/blog` subfolder, where I have my WordPress-based [blog](https://www.doviddebresser.info/blog/), it doesn't work. What do I mean that it doesn't work? When opening a page on my blog, a secure page (using https) is opened, and that is good. No issues there.

But if on the website or subdomain I manually enter a non-secure link (using just http, without the "s"), it automatically gets redirected to a secure one (https, with the "s"), **but on the blog that doesn't happen**, even though the same RewriteRule is used .htaccess of the `blog` subfolder as in the main domain and subdomain subfolder.

The full text of the  `blog`'s subfolder's .htaccess file is:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
# The directives (lines) between `BEGIN WordPress` and `END WordPress` are
# dynamically generated, and should only be modified via WordPress filters.
# Any changes to the directives between these markers will be overwritten.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /blog/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
RewriteEngine On
# Force www.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
# Force https (SSL)
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
# Use PHP70 as default
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php70 .php
<IfModule mod_suphp.c>
    suPHP_ConfigPath /opt/php70/lib
</IfModule>
```

On a sidenote, I wasn't sure if I need the second `RewriteEngine On`, or if perhaps it even makes trouble, so I tried both with and without, with the same result.

Comment: Just put https related rules to the top of .htaccess

Comment: B"H

Hello Dusan Bajic

That seems to solve the problem. Incredible. Why is that?

Sincerely, Dovid

Comment: Well, already existing wordpress rules have [L] flag which prevent execution of rules below them: everything will be rewritten to /blog/index.php, and then caught by  `RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]`

Comment: Dynamic configuration files (".htaccess") are processed from top to bottom. So the further up a rule is the earlier it gets processed. And often that is a first-come-first-serve process...